# ld: framework not found SDWebImage

Tags: swift3, xcode9, sdwebimage

I am using Xcode Version 9.0.1, If I create a new project and install the sdwebimage using cocoapods, it works fine and give no build error.
Where as If I added it to an existing project I am getting:

```
ld: framework not found SDWebImage
[![clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)][1]][1]
```

[image: Error screenshot]

This is how my pod file looks like:

```
    platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'test' do
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'AKSideMenu'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.0.0'
    pod 'FacebookCore'
    pod 'FacebookLogin'
    pod 'FacebookShare', :git => 'https://github.com/1amageek/facebook-sdk-swift'
    pod 'CMPageControl'
    pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0'
    pod 'PinCodeTextField', :git => "https://github.com/tkach/PinCodeTextField"
#    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

I have check the `Framework Search Path` and `Other Linker Flags` Everything looks fine. But I am failing to build the project with sdwebimage.
[image: Framework Search Paths]

Answer (score 1):

As a heads up, I tried the solutions above, and they did not work for me -- returned the same error shown above. However, I looked at my terminal from when I installed `SDWebImage`, and it said something I missed:

`[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use FILENAME.xcworkspace for this project from now on.`

Make sure you are not using the `.xcodeproj` file like I was. Once I changed to the workspace, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project's build folder (**Product/Clean Build Folder**, <kbd>^⌘C</kbd>).

Comment: I did every thing, like Build, Clean but noting works. I manually added the sdwebimage to path where it is giving error and it builds.

Comment: But when I tried to install on my iPhone again same error.

Answer (score 0):

I shutdown my system and then turn it on and I just replace `pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'` with `pod 'SDWebImage'` and it starts to build. I almost wasted 3 hours to get it worked.

One more mistake was, In `"Edit Scheme"` under Build `"Find Implicit Dependencies"` was unchecked, That was the main problem, I mark it check and it start working fine.

Answer (score 0):

for my case I did a search for 'SDWebImage' on the side menu. and it turns out that there is a build setting that hasn't been updated yet.

1. Project Target
2. Build Settings
3. Other Linker Flags
4. please remove if it is bold it will return to the original setting